# Cadence detection API for Samsung Galaxy Watch 6 (Wear OS)?

Tags: android, wear-os, cadence, samsung-health, samsung-galaxy-watch

Is there any other Cadence API for Wear OS?
I'm trying to calculate running cadence and display the information on the UI, but I have no idea how to do it.
I found `val RUNNING_STEPS: DeltaDataType<Long,IntervalDataPoint<Long>>`
is it can use in real time ?

1. The Google Fit API does not suit me.
2. I tried to write an algorithm using the accelerometer but failed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Look into Health Services on Wear OS (https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/health/services/client/data/DataType). Cadence isn't a datatype, but you can get speed, steps, and pace and make inferences from that.